# Моожно ли использоваться цикл for внутри while?

Tags: javascript

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня зацикливается код

```js
var arr = ['{}', '()', '[]'];
var str = '()([]){}';
do {
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (str.indexOf(arr[i] != -1)) {
      str = str.replace(arr[i], '');
      count++
    }
  }
} while (count != 0);
```

str может быть в другом виде.

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Но если вы укажете зачем вам это потребовалось, возможно мы подскажем более изящное решение.

Comment: Просто я столкнулся с такой пробелой, что у меня зацикливается код, хотя не должен, проверил через console.log все переменные, по идее всё должно работать чётко, но что-то не выходит
`do{count = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
   if(str.indexOf(arr[i]!=-1)){str = str.replace(arr[i], '');count++}
  }
 }while(count!=0);
 console.log(str);
`
Массив arr это` [ '{}' , '()' , '||' ] `
`str = '(((({}))){})||' `и т.д.
там разные варианты

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и вставьте в него этот код. В комментах код __нечитабелен__.

Comment: И на будущее - спрашивайте о __настоящей проблеме__. Как вы понимаете, ответ "Да, можно" вашей настоящей проблеме никак не поможет.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: do{count = 0;count++} while(count!=0); - это бесконечный цикл =) и он у вас в коде =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков каждый раз он обнуляет count и увеличивает только если срабатывает if

Comment: Я вам на ошибку указал, дальше дело ваше что с ней делать =)
А теперь по самому алгоритму - если это алгоритм "проверки" скобок - он не верен в корне. =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, ты неправильно указал :-)

Comment: @Sergey, проблема в опечатке, вместо `if (str.indexOf(arr[i] != -1)) {` должно было быть `if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {`

Comment: @Grundy вполне возможно, но тем не менее если я прав насчет алгоритма - то это не решение =) точнее это одно из возможных ужаснейших решений =)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, только что сам заметил

Comment: Воздержитесь от оскорблений =)